# bash script create multiple files and replace a string incrementally in each file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have an *example.txt* file, in which there is a certain string **HEYIAMHERE** appearing multiple times.

I want to generate 50 other **txt** files like the **example.txt** file, but each time rename the output file using this pattern **2017file_01.txt**, each time incrementing by one, and in each file replace all the occurrences of the string **HEYIAMHERE** in that output file by the filename itself without the extension of course.

example.txt

```
Lorem ipsum HEYIAMHERE dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit
Proin ut HEYIAMHERE velit sed mauris sagittis
Etiam lacus tortor, suscipit eget odio et, 
iaculis egestas risus HEYIAMHERE.
```

the result will be:

2017file_01.txt

```
Lorem ipsum 2017file_01 dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit
Proin ut 2017file_01 velit sed mauris sagittis
Etiam lacus tortor, suscipit eget odio et, 
iaculis egestas risus 2017file_01.
```

2017file_02.txt

```
Lorem ipsum 2017file_02 dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit
Proin ut 2017file_02 velit sed mauris sagittis
Etiam lacus tortor, suscipit eget odio et, 
iaculis egestas risus 2017file_02.
```

and so on.

Could somebody help me? I am lost and don't know where to start? I am a newbie in bash.

```
input_file=$1
old=HEYIAMHERE
new=2017file_
for num in $(seq 1 50)
do
  sed "s/$old/$new$num/" $input_file > "$new$num.txt"
done
```

Comment: And what exactly is not working? The zero-padding? Why don't you say so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to include `-w` in seq to have your zeros included as well:

```
input_file=$1
old=HEYIAMHERE
new=2017file_
for num in $(seq -w 01 50)
do
  sed "s/$old/$new$num/" $input_file > "$new$num.txt"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will  take content of example.txt and copy it 50 times into 50 different files, replacing "HEYIAMHERE" with each file name.

```
#!/bin/bash

var="`less ./example.txt`"
for NUMBER in {1..50}
do
    foo="2017file_$NUMBER"
    echo ${var//HEYIAMHERE/$foo} > ./$foo.txt
    echo "...$foo"
done
```

- var="`less ./example.txt`": Captures the content of example.txt as a string
- `echo ${var//HEYIAMHERE/$foo} > ./$foo.txt`: Replaces HEYIAMHERE with name file and writes it to according file.

  To replace ALL the matches:
  `${string//substring_to_replace/replacement}`

  To replace THE FIRST match:
  `${string/substring_to_replace/replacement}`

Answer (score 0):

In place of seq you could also simply use brace expansion:

```
for num in {01..50}
...
```